# p:datatable incorrectly rendered in firefox

Tags: jsf, firefox, primefaces

I have problem with displaying datatables in primefaces on firefox.
View has four datatables, check link below:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5tqN.png]

When the same view is displaying in firefox datatables crushed:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkV8B.png]

Firefox correctly display this view after zoom out to 120%:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wuy2U.png]

Browers like: Maxthon, IE, edge, opera correctly displays this view, but we have one customer which used firefox and we need to display this view correctly on firefox.

Comment: Maybe post your xhtml so we can see if there's anything weird going on there

Comment: Most likely custom css related as was in you wrong answer